# Running scikit-learn on multiple cores: OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I need to run a classifier on multiple cores. I am using scikit-learn and Python 2.7.

The GridSearchCV module from scikit-learn has a parameter called n_jobs that will allow you run the Grid search on multiple cores. When I set this parameter to 10, I get the memory allocation error shown below. Any thoughts? My machine has 32 cores.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

...

w.start()
File "../anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
File "/home/nhailu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 121, in __init__
    self.pid = os.fork()

OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the most likely culprit is that you have a very large grid to search through. Considering setting `pre_dispatch` to a multiple of your number of jobs.

Also, the way `joblib` works, you need to make sure your master script is guarded by the 'if main' idiom:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # your script here, otherwise every core will execute all of your code
```

From the [GridSearchCV documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV):

> pre_dispatch : int, or string, optional
>
> Controls the number of jobs that get dispatched during parallel execution. Reducing this number can be useful to avoid an explosion of memory consumption when more jobs get dispatched than CPUs can process. This parameter can be:
>
> None, in which case all the jobs are immediately created and spawned. Use this for lightweight and fast-running jobs, to avoid delays due to on-demand spawning of the jobs
>
> An int, giving the exact number of total jobs that are spawned
>
> A string, giving an expression as a function of n_jobs, as in ‘2*n_jobs’